# Can't open any report in the workSpace: Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Last week i had given a WorkSpace a dedicated capacity so i can use the Powrer BI Embedded Service.

From Yesterday i was getting this error when opening any report in the workSpace.
I thaught the workSpace reached its limit of the dedicated capacity, but even so why can't i opent the reports directly in the workspace?

Error msg:

```
Unable to load model

 Unable to load the model schema associated with this report. Check the connection to the server, then try again.
For more information, check the technical details. If contacting support, provide these details.
Capacity operation failed with error code NotFound
Activity ID7aede53-3be5-432d-945d-6b50ff630040
Correlation ID2f85bd9f-4eaf-6721-7653-5696442536cc
Requisition ID88fe7e71-b81b-bf6c-93c8-21cd2252df2e
Time Wed Sep 16 2020 09:35:52 GMT + 0100 (West African Standard Time)
Service version13.0.14254.53
Client version2008.5.02820-train
Cluster URI https://wabi-europe-north-b-redirect.analysis.windows.net/
```

Any Help and Thanks.

Comment: Obviously it can't find the attached capacity. Check it in the portal, try to detach and re-attach the capacity to this workspace.

Comment: And check your capacity is not paused in the case of embedded.

Comment: Problem solved.Thanks

Comment: "Capacity operation failed with error code NotFound"  on all my reports brought me here,  I haven't changed anything on the reports for weeks, and were used daily just fine.  @zarzou how did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

As per Microsoft documentation: Pausing your capacity prevents you from being billed. Pausing your capacity is great if you don't need to use the capacity for a period of time.

Capacity may be paused automatically due to Global Azure billing issues/limits - I could not find anything yet to prove this, however did see this happen in the past.

It is best to create monitors or check via CLI if Capacity is paused or removed all together by mistake: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/monitor-power-bi-embedded

One of the ways to bring capacity back online is to start it from Azure portal under "Power BI Embedded" area.